# Configuring CSS/LESS files with webpack

Tags: html, css, webpack

I would like to compile the LESS file into normal CSS then add it to the `/build` folder but I'm getting an error:

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { body {
                                                               ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:528:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:483:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/charisse/react/wanderlust/webpack.config.js:3:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:556:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:483:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
```

I understand the error is coming from the LESS file, but I don't know how to solve it?

```
body {
    background: yellow;
}
```

I've followed tutorials and `webpack.config.js` seems to be pretty much built the same way:

```
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var Less = require('./app/css/styles.less');

var HtmlWebpackPluginConfig = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: './app/index.html',
    inject: 'body'
});

var ExtractTextPluginConfig = new ExtractTextPlugin('./build/styles.css');

module.exports = {
    entry: './app/js/index.js',
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/build',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {   test: /\.less$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader!autoprefixer!less-loader')
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [ HtmlWebpackPluginConfig, ExtractTextPluginConfig]
}
```

Also is there any difference between loaders implemented like `'style-loader', 'css-loader'` and `style-loader!css-loader`?

Is it also possible to just inject the compiled LESS file into the `index.html` that's inside the `/build` folder?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are importing the less file, webpack cannot interpret it so it fails.

In short you don't need this bit:

```
var Less = require('./app/css/styles.less');
```

To answer your question about the string syntax vs the array there isn't much of a difference you can omit the -loader bit all together webpack is smart enough to add that on for you.

the second question you asked about, you are already doing with the html-webpack-plugin.

Comment: Thanks! I managed to make it work. The problem I now have is that when I run `webpack -p`, the `/build` folder does get built with the `index.html` and `bundle.js` but the LESS file has not been transformed?

Answer (score 0):

In your index.js (entry file) you need to require the less file so it can run through the loader like so

```
var css = require('../css/styles.less');
```

I have taken the liberty in refactoring your webpack.config

```
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
//var Less = require('./app/css/styles.less');

module.exports = {
    entry: './app/js/index.js',
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/build',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {   test: /\.less$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css!less')
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [ 
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './app/index.html',
            inject: 'body'
        }), 
        new ExtractTextPlugin('./styles.css')
    ]
}
```